# Catching the Link click when in the same component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

I have a `NavBar` that has a Logo on it, that contains a `Link` to the `Home` page `"/"`. The application starts from the main page and then its UI will start changing based on user's choices. I want to give the user a chance to reset everything if he is still in the `Home` component and clicks the `Logo`.

**App.js**

```
...
import Home from './views/Home';
import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar';
...

render() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        <main ref={(element) => { this.mainElement = element; }}>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
         ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Inside `NavBar` I have a logo that has a Link attached to it:

**NavBar.js**

```
  <div className="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <Link to="/" className="navbar-item">
      <img className="navbar-logo" src={logo} alt="" />
    </Link>
  </div>
```

**Home.js**

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    //Link was clicked
}
```

If I am already in the component `Home`. How can I know that the `Logo's Link` was clicked and refresh the state of the page to default?

Comment: It looks like [`Link`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) will pass any extra props to the underlying `a` tag. You could pass it an `onClick` and reset the state there? Untested, just an idea.

Comment: That was one of the ideas but I thought that maybe there is a way for the `Home` component to know that the `Link` was clicked.

Comment: Assuming the `onClick` method works, you'd just have to pass it through props from `Home` so that it resets `Home`'s state.

Comment: I am a bit new to react, how do you pass `onclick` from 1 component to other through a third component?

Comment: @kataroty If you click on an image and you are listening for image's click with an event handler declared in home, then home knows the a click occured on image.

Comment: I just realized that the top code snippet wasn't the `Home` component. That makes it more complicated...

Comment: I will edit it with classNames.

Comment: So, Home is a sibling of Navbar component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to communicate this information. Here what I suggest to do:

1.The App component has the state of the application, storing all information needed to both its child Components. Add inside the state a value clicked, that is true if the image was clicked; false otherwise.

2. Add an event handler inside App component. Pass it to the navbar, so you can use for the image tag.
3. Pass the state to home via props; when it changes, re-render starts and home knows.

App

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
     clicked: false,
  }

 handler = () => { this.setState({clicked: true})}

 componentDidMount() {
  this.timerID = setInterval(
    () => this.setState({clicked: false}),
    2000
  );
 }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  } 

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
      <Navbar clicked={this.handler} />
      <Home click={this.state.clicked} />
    </div>
   );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

Navbar

```
class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
         <button onClick={this.props.clicked} >Click Me!</button>
      );
     }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Home

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log('rendering...')
      return(
         <p>The logo was clicked: {this.props.click ? "yes" : "no"} </p>
      );
 }
}

export default Home;
```

When the click on Button, the state change from false to true and from true to true. After the first click, react actually re-render the home elements, but it looks the same. To show that something happens I use two lifecycle method to reset the value from true to false. Without timer, if there's a log on home, developers can look that rendering happens at each button (or image clicks).

This links can help you now and when you'll have a bit more experience:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react-communicating-between-components

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to to know that the `Link` was clicked when inside the `Home` component.

Comment: You can pass via props

Comment: Sorry, the question might have been a bit misleading at first. NavBar is not defined in the `Home` Component but in the `App.js`, which routes to `Home`

Comment: Can you share with us the component tree?

Comment: If my edited question is not enough then yes I can share.

Comment: All right thank you for this, I will take a look at it soon and then will probably upvote your answer because it seems that It will work.

Comment: With the answer that you wrote, this functionality will work only once? Meaning once it is set to true, it will never be false again and thus repeated clicks wont work?

Comment: Ouch! I'm thinking to a solution for this bug. I'll update my answer soon...

Comment: @kataroty This functionality works fine! every time you click the button, react render the same message, but for the user nopthing happens. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: For some reason I am not able to call the fucntion from my "NavBar" method so I am still working on that, but thank you for taking your time.

Comment: I tried passing on a random `string` as a `prop` and that it recognizes but with the `onClick`, nothing happens.

Comment: @Kataroty. I apologize, but a bug exists in my previous answer. If you work on my new answer, with console.log in Home component or with timers, it's works.