# Get data from one component in another in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application in reactjs. I want to get data from the input, from Component.js, into Component2.js. The function that get data from input is stored in sources.js.

```js
export const getData = e => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  console.log(value);
  return value;
};
```

Unfortunately when i want to get data in Component2, i don't get anything.
**Question**: How keeping this structure of folders to get  data from Component1 in Component2?
**Demo** https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-vaughan-62mqe?file=/src/Component2.js

Comment: Is there any hierarchy, like component2 is parent or child of component1?

Comment: You can use context api.  to archive this

Comment: this question is very close to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935187/catching-the-link-click-when-in-the-same-component-react/61935271#61935271

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to achieve this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can lifted up your state from child to parent and then pass that data from parent to another child (sibling). Here is the example:

**Parent Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Child from "./Child";
import Sibling from "./Sibling";

function CParent(props) {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

    function setOpeningValue(value) {
        console.log('From Child to Parent:' + value);
        setValue(value);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Child setOpeningValue={setOpeningValue}/>
            <Sibling value={value}/>
        </div>
    );
}
export default CParent;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

// Child to Parent communication
function Child(props) {
    const {setOpeningValue} = props;
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    function clickHandler() {
        setOpeningValue(`changes is ${value}`);
    }

    function changeHandler(event) {
        setValue(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={changeHandler} />
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>pass data to parent</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Child;
```

**Sibling Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function Sibling(props) {
    const {value} = props;

    return (
        <div>
            This value is showing from Child to Parent to Another Child (Sibling): {value}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Sibling;
```